# qunit + mockjax: When should I call mockjaxClear in async tests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, qunit, mockjax

I'm testing my frontend code using [qunit](http://qunitjs.com/) and [mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax). The structure of AJAX tests in [mockjax's own test code](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax/blob/master/test/test.js) looks like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YaELF/1/)):

```
var testURL = "/test/data",
    testData = { a: 1, b: "c" };

asyncTest("AJAX response test", 1, function() {
    $.mockjax({
        url: testURL,
        responseText : JSON.stringify(testData)
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: testURL,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            deepEqual(data, testData, 'AJAX response is OK');
        },
        complete: function() {
            start();
        }
    });

    $.mockjaxClear();
});
```

According to the [mockjax documentation](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax/blob/master/README.md):

```
* $.mockjaxClear() 
    Removes all mockjax handlers.
```

What I don't understand is why `mockjaxClear` is called right after the `$.ajax()` call. The problem is if it does some sort of cleanup, as the documentation says, this cleanup will run *before* the AJAX response arrives (pls. see the console of [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YaELF/1/)). It seems more logical for me to do the cleanup in the handler of the `complete` event. **Can anyone explain me why it is better to call mockjaxClear after `$.ajax()`?**

Comment: since jquery-mockjax v1.6.0, released 2014-10-09, `$.mockjaxClear()` has been renamed to  `$.mockjax.clear()` . See [ChangeLog](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the code, you will see that the cleanup does not affect already "running" calls. It just makes sure that any subsequent `$.ajax()` will call jQuery's original method and that other internal state (but again, not affecting already pending "requests") is cleaned.

This may help to ensure that the `$.ajax()` call under test test is only sent once (if more are sent they will fail, moreover the `start()` method will be called again, reporting the error to Qunit).

It could also be this way just to keep code clean (less stuff in the callback handlers).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should be running `$.mockjaxClear` anywhere in your tests actually.  QUnit provides lifecycle hooks for tests run within a module, the important one being teardown in this case.

http://api.qunitjs.com/module/

Using that, your code should be something like

```
module( "myapi", {
    teardown: function() {
        $.mockjaxClear();
    }
});

asyncTest( "sometest", function() {
    // test definition
});
```

If you wanted to, you could even move your mock setups into the `setup` lifecycle hook to make your actual test code more compact and focused just on the test itself, not setup/teardown.